# Is there any way to get information of database connections from the apk files of android

Tags: android, database, connection, apk

If yes, how?

And if no, then how is the connection made?

And is there any possibility to edit the queries in apk to get result of other required fields the way I want.

Comment: like suppose, there is a app, that has some information about thier product.
but I want to see all the products...
can I edit and get all the products data through the app, by editing the query !!

Comment: what do you mean by that your app database or any other apk file database?